# SQL Constraint on column value depending on value of other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

First, I have simple `[SomeType]` table, with columns `[ID]` and `[Name]`.

Also I have `[SomeTable]` table, with fields like:

```
[ID], 
[SomeTypeID] (FK), 
[UserID] (FK), 
[IsExpression]
```

Finally, I have to made on database layer a constraint that:

- for concrete `[SomeType]` IDs (actually, for all but one),
- for same    `UserID`,
- only one entry should have `[IsExpression]` equal to 1
  (`IsExpression` is of `BIT` type)

I don't know if it's complex condition or not, but I have no idea how to write it. How would you implement such constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_SomeTable] ON [dbo].[SomeTable]
(
    [UserID] ASC
)
WHERE ([SomeTypeID] <> 1 AND [IsExpression] = 1)
```

or:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_SomeTable] ON [dbo].[SomeTable]
(
    [UserID] ASC,
    [SomeTypeID] ASC
)
WHERE ([SomeTypeID] <> 1 AND [IsExpression] = 1)
```

Depends on what you are trying to achieve. Only one `[IsExpression] = 1` within one user without consideration of `[SomeTypeID]` or you want only one `[IsExpression] = 1` within one user and one `[SomeTypeID]`.

Comment: will index help me to avoid adding new entry with also [IsExpression] true, if this user already has IsExpression true for this SomeType ?

Comment: @prvit, the second index is exactly what you want

Comment: @prvit yes, if a index is created as `UNIQUE` then this means you cannot enter any duplicate records into the fields which are part of the index.